# will ajax calling a php file / database every 1 second crash the site with multiple users?

Tags: php, ajax, database, while-loop

I am building a web app that gets data from the database using a ajax call to a php file accessing the database every 1 second. it works great but my question is will this cause performance issues if say 1000 people were on it simultaneously?Will I have bandwidth issues?

```
//Calling Images

repeatAjax();
function repeatAjax(){
  $.ajax({    
    type: "GET",
    url: "get_feed.php",             
    dataType: "html",                  
    success: function(response){                    
        $("#response").html(response); 
    },
      complete: function() {
           setTimeout(repeatAjax,1000);
       }
    });
};
```

my php file just has a while loop pulling some images from the db..
Thanks!

Comment: Assuming it completes in less then a second then probably not, but it's probably also not the best approach.  If it takes like 10s to complete then you might have issues.  For things like this you have to ask your self does the data really need to be updated every second, most people have about a 10s attention span anyway...  You can also check if the first call is complete before firing off a second call, so as not to back log them.

Comment: Ya guess i shoulf of added it request every second because there is a timer on each image otherwise yes i wouldnt call it every second.. thanks!

Comment: Also you don't need to use ajax for images with php, you can point the image src at a php file and then with the proper content headers just spit out the file contents, no javascript needed.  I did this before when I was storing files and thumbnails in a zip file on the server.

Comment: What about if there is text outputting as well like the username?

Comment: Well if you put text content into an image file, like with notepad++ i think it will wreck the image.  That's basically what you would be doing.  Content is content, and all webcontent is text with special headers. That's why we can json encode stuff, it's just "special" text.  That said it's not a good idea to mix and match content types in the same request.

Comment: but you can do this `<img src="script.php" />` then it the php file pull the image out and do something like this`header('Content-Type image/png'); echo $image;`  although I would try to hide the extension.

Comment: Sure, just don't quote me on the exact syntax, that's just off the top of my head.  lol.  Yea I used it like I said because I wanted 5 thumbnails and a full size image stored in a single zip.  Then I just read out the image I needed from the zip file with php.  You can also use `$f=fopen('php://output'); fwite($f, $ln);` if you don't want to use echo.  http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you will have bandwidth issues every time your script "get_feed.php" is called. Also, the question of whether your server will crash depends on what server you have (the size of its main memory and processor speed, etc).

Each time "get_feed.php" is called, your server will fire up the processor and use some main memory and if these resources are not large enough to run this script a 1000 times simultaneously; it will crash :)

Comment: Ya as I suspected.. Thanks!

Comment: A script getting called 1000 (or many more) times simultaneously should be no big deal. It all depends on how you have allocated memory in a given script to your variables and how wasteful/resourceful you are in using whatever memory you have.